# Problem while writing code for diy HID Arduino Gamepad

Tags: c, arduino, arduino-ide, hid, gamepad

Hello there I'm trying to create a diy HID Gamepad that I will later integrate into something bigger, using the Arduino Pro Micro but I'm new to Arduino/MCUs development/programming, I trying to create a gamepad with a 4x4 buttons matrix and two Azoteq TPS43-201A-S Capacitive Trackpads which use the Azoteq IQS570 Capacitive touch controller, and I'm not sure if I wrote the code for the matrix right and I have no idea how to write code for the trackpad, here is how far I came with the code.

```
#include <Keypad.h>
#include <Gamepad.h>

// Define the 4x4 button matrix
const byte ROWS = 4;
const byte COLS = 4;
char keys[ROWS][COLS] = {
  {'Y', 'X', 'B', 'A'},
  {'LEFT', 'RIGHT', 'UP', 'DOWN'},
  {'LB', 'RB', 'SE', 'MU'},
  {'JL', 'JR', 'E1', 'E2'}
};

// Define the pin numbers for the rows and columns of the matrix
byte rowPins[ROWS] = {9, 8, 7, 6}; // Row pins are connected to Arduino pins 9, 8, 7, 6
byte colPins[COLS] = {5, 4, 3, 2}; // Column pins are connected to Arduino pins 5, 4, 3, 2

Keypad keypad = Keypad(makeKeymap(keys), rowPins, colPins, ROWS, COLS);
Gamepad gp;

void setup() {
  for (byte i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
    pinMode(rowPins[i], INPUT_PULLUP);
  }

  for (byte i = 0; i < COLS; i++) {
    pinMode(colPins[i], INPUT_PULLUP);
  }

  pinMode(A0, INPUT); //right stick y-axis
  pinMode(A1, INPUT); //right stick x-axis
  pinMode(A2, INPUT); //left stick y-axis
  pinMode(A3, INPUT); //left stick x-axis
  pinMode(A4, INPUT); //left trigger
  pinMode(A5, INPUT); //right trigger

  calibrate();
}

void loop() {
  int rt, lt, lx, ly, rx, ry;

  rt = analogRead(A5);
  lt = analogRead(A4);
  lx = analogRead(A3);
  ly = analogRead(A2);
  rx = analogRead(A1);
  ry = analogRead(A0);

  // Convert 0-1000 to -127 - 127
  rt = floor((rt - rightTcenter) * multiplierRT);
  lt = floor((lt - leftTcenter) * multiplierLT);
  lx = floor((lx - leftXcenter) * multiplierLX);
  ly = floor((ly - leftYcenter) * multiplierLY);
  rx = floor((rx - rightXcenter) * multiplierRX);
  ry = floor((ry - rightYcenter) * multiplierRY);

  if (rt > 127) rt = 127;
  if (lt > 127) lt = 127;
  if (lx > 127) lx = 127;
  if (ly > 127) ly = 127;
  if (rx > 127) rx = 127;
  if (ry > 127) ry = 127;

  gp.setRightTaxis(rt);
  gp.setLeftTaxis(lt);
  gp.setLeftXaxis(lx);
  gp.setRightXaxis(rx);
  gp.setLeftYaxis(ly);
  gp.setRightYaxis(ry);

  char key = keypad.getKey();

  if (key) {
    handleButtonPress(key);
  }

  delay(20);
}

void handleButtonPress(char button) {
  for (byte row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) {
    for (byte col = 0; col < COLS; col++) {
      if (button == keys[row][col]) {
        if (digitalRead(rowPins[row]) == LOW && digitalRead(colPins[col]) == LOW) {
          gp.setButtonState(row * COLS + col, true);
        } else {
          gp.setButtonState(row * COLS + col, false);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

int rightTcenter = 500;
int leftTcenter = 500;
int rightXcenter = 500;
int rightYcenter = 500;
int leftXcenter = 500;
int leftYcenter = 500;
double multiplierRT = 0.254; //127 / 500
double multiplierLT = 0.254;
double multiplierRX = 0.254;
double multiplierRY = 0.254;
double multiplierLX = 0.254;
double multiplierLY = 0.254;

void calibrate() {
  int rt, lt, lx, ly, rx, ry;
  int i = 0;
  while (i < 13) {
    rt = analogRead(A5);
    lt = analogRead(A4);
    lx = analogRead(A3);
    ly = analogRead(A2);
    rx = analogRead(A1);
    ry = analogRead(A0);
    bool validRT = rt > (rightTcenter - 100) && rt < (rightTcenter + 100);
    bool validLT = lt > (leftTcenter - 100) && lt < (leftTcenter + 100);
    bool validLX = lx > (leftXcenter - 100) && lx < (leftXcenter + 100);
    bool validLY = ly > (leftYcenter - 100) && ly < (leftYcenter + 100);
    bool validRX = rx > (rightXcenter - 100) && rx < (rightXcenter + 100);
    bool validRY = ry > (rightYcenter - 100) && ry < (rightYcenter + 100);
    if (validRT && validLT && validLX && validLY && validRX && validRY) {
      i++;
      //nothing to do here!
    } else
      i = 0;
    delay(20);
  }
  rightTcenter = rt;
  leftTcenter = lt;
  leftXcenter = lx;
  leftYcenter = ly;
  rightXcenter = rx;
  rightYcenter = ry;
  multiplierRT = (double)127 / (double)rt;
  multiplierLT = (double)127 / (double)lt;
  multiplierLX = (double)127 / (double)lx;
  multiplierLY = (double)127 / (double)ly;
  multiplierRX = (double)127 / (double)rx;
  multiplierRY = (double)127 / (double)ry;
}
```

I tried giving each button a pin, but there weren't enough pins. So, I switched to a matrix. I also tried searching online to find information about the TPS43-201A-S or the IQS570, but it looks like nobody knows anything except two or three people – one of them on Reddit. However, he used the trackpad with Linux, while I'm trying to use it with an Arduino Pro Micro.

Comment: For keypad matrix, you are using the pins for its digital functions instead of as analog pins, you might need to setup some of the pins as `INPUT_PULLUP` if you don't have external pull-up resistor. Take a look at [this tutorial](https://arduinogetstarted.com/tutorials/arduino-keypad). *"About the TPS43-201A-S or the IQS570, but it looks like nobody knows anything"...* IQS5xx datasheet is available [online](https://www.azoteq.com/images/stories/pdf/iqs572ev02_datasheet.pdf) which included link to library for Arduino.

Answer (score 0):

1. You've unnecessarily duplicated your array of key names in `keys` and `matrixKeys` (minor issue, not the cause of your trouble)
2. You're passing `char button` as the parameter to your `handleButtonPress` function, and then inside that function you're comparing it to elements of your (duplicate) `matrixKeys` array. That will never work - your `matrixKeys` is an array of string pointers, so comparing those to a `char` will never result in a match.

It appears that you're also using the Arduino Keypad library incorrectly.
The documentation [here](https://playground.arduino.cc/Code/Keypad/) seems to imply that you're supposed to initialize it with an array of `char`s, not an array of string pointers as you've done.
So your `keys[ROWS][COLS]` should be initialized with something more like:

```c
{
  {'Y', 'X', 'B', 'A'},
  {'L', 'R', 'U', 'D'},
  {'1', '2', '3', '4'},
  {'5', '6', '7', '8'}
};
```

Feel free to replace the `1` thru `8` digits with something more meaningful for you, as long as they stay single characters.
Then inside `handleButtonPress` there's no need to declare a new array containing the same set of `char` elements, just reference `keys`.

Comment: OK I have done it, but do you anything about the trackpad or the touch controller I mentioned earlier

Comment: @BONIIXSAbonion1500 No sorry I don't know anything about those. The Stack Exchange Q&A format also works better if you try to keep your question focused on one thing at a time, so you might be better off creating a separate question (or 2) for that. Don't know that it would be on-topic for stackoverflow though.